# How to get the Position of a paragraph in google docs API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Using GAS, I'm trying to navigate [paragraphs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) in a google doc and record their starting [position](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position) so that I can display an interactive navigation menu in a sidebar. But I can't find any GAS method that returns the position of a paragraph (or an element for that matter), except when the cursor is within that paragraph. I thought of inserting bookmarks to retrieve their positions, but it seems that one cannot insert a bookmark without having first a position…

Am I missing anything?

Note that I'm aware of the fact that headings have hash locations (except for normal paragraphs) that are easy to retrieve using a TOC; but I can't use these hash locations directly in any GAS add-on, because the caja compiler prevents it. Besides, I'd like to list more than headings in my navigation menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Document.newPosition(element, offset)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newPosition(Element,Integer)) method, where `element` is your `Paragraph` object and `offset` is `0`.

For example:

```
var newParagraph = body.appendParagraph("some text");
var paragraphPosition = doc.newPosition(newParagraph, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! The complete sequence is thus: 
let positions = [];
body.getParagraphs().forEach( par => positions.push (doc.newPosition (par, 0) ) );