# In Google Docs, how do I make every paragraph have its own #heading tag in its URL without using a Style?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

I have some documents in which every paragraph has its own #heading URL tag, even if it is Normal Text (no Style applied), and it helps a lot to externally refer to a specific part of the document, but I've never known how I got there. These documents were not imported from other formats; they were originally created in Google Docs.

Would anybody know how to make every paragraph have its own #heading URL tag? This avoids having to add a new bookmark every time on every paragraph, and avoids individual paragraphs from appearing in a table of contents.

Please, no bookmarks solutions, no "use a Style to look like Normal text" solutions.

Comment: Would maybe the solution to question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/103145/203891 produce that now each paragraph will have its own #heading tag in the URL?